# Name mangling differences on same compiler, same settings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assimp, name-mangling

I'm trying to link ASSIMP into my project, on Windows 10 Visual Studio Community 2019 RC. I've built ASSIMP with CMake and the same version of VS. I've linked the lib file so that is all working.

```
mesh.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
"public: class aiScene const * __cdecl Assimp::Importer::ReadFile(char const *,unsigned int)"
(?ReadFile@Importer@Assimp@@QEAAPEBVaiScene@@PEBDI@Z)
referenced in function
"public: static void __cdecl citrus::graphics::mesh::convertAnimationFromCollada(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)"
(?convertAnimationFromCollada@mesh@graphics@citrus@@SAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z)
```

The key part is:

```
?ReadFile@Importer@Assimp@@QEAAPEBVaiScene@@PEBDI@Z
```

When I view the symbols in my generated assimp lib file I see:

```
?ReadFile@Importer@Assimp@@QEAAPEBUaiScene@@PEBDI@Z
```

So as you can see the name is slightly different, with the difference being QEAAPEBV changed to QEAAPEBU. What could cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `undname` command like tool, we find the two names are the mangled forms of

```
public: class aiScene const * __ptr64 __cdecl Assimp::Importer::ReadFile(char const * __ptr64,unsigned int) __ptr64
```

and

```
public: struct aiScene const * __ptr64 __cdecl Assimp::Importer::ReadFile(char const * __ptr64,unsigned int) __ptr64
```

for the `V` and `U` versions.  So you can see that the difference is one is declared as a `class aiScene`, the other a `struct aiScene`.

Somewhere in your code you are inconsistently declaring what `aiScene` is.

Comment: well that's a shame because all the declarations and definitions are in the ASSIMP headers.... But thanks a ton for the info, I had no idea that tool existed.

Comment: Well, it turns out I was incorrectly forward declaring aiScene. Always a bad practice but I didn't know it could cause problems in this way. Solved!

Comment: Except MSVC is non-compliant in a particular corner case: Per [dcl.type.elab]/3, both `class Name;` and `struct Name;` are valid forward declarations of a class defined with `class Name { /*...*/ };` or `struct Name { /*...*/ };`.  But when a translation unit has such a forward declaration but does not also contain the type's definition, and a function signature includes a pointer or reference to that type, the mangled name of the function will depend on the class-key used in the forward declaration, and this can fail to link with a mangled name from another translation unit.

Comment: @BWG Your code was likely technically fine - see my previous comment. But just changing the forward declaration to make MSVC happy is probably the easiest way forward.